# Memory-mapped I/O and Peripheral-mapped I/O in 8085 microprocessor

Tags: microprocessor

In the book it is given that:

> "to identify the I/O devices these devices can be interfaced using address from memory space: MEMORY-MAPPED I/O. Another option is to have a separate numbering (addressing) scheme for I/O devices. The 8085 has separate 8-bit addressing scheme:
>   PERIPHERAL-MAPPED I/O."

When the 8085 microprocessor has fixed 64kB of memory which it uses for addressing the different memory locations then how it can share that memory with the I/O address (i.e., for any external peripheral) in memory mapped and how can it use "separate 8-bit addressing scheme" when it has fixed memory in it.

I am unable to understand this. If anyone knows this please explain this in detail or tell me where it is explained in detail.

Comment: It is relatively easy to support multiple address spaces. A processor puts out a signal which identifies the address space it is using for that external address/data access. The other signals, such as address and data, can be reused.

Comment: To further gbulmer's comment, the program does different things addressing memory vs. I/O. I don't remember the 8085 specifically, but I believe there are different instructions for memory access and I/O access.

Comment: 8085 instructions IN (0xDB) and OUT (0xD3) read and write the I/O address space.

Answer (score 2):

The 8085 has different instructions for accessing main memory and I/O 'memory'. In addition to the standard memory interface pins the 8085 also provides a pin that identifies whether a memory access cycle is accessing main or I/O. This extra line is used in the select logic of both main and I/O 'memory'.

But there is no law that I/O can only be accessed by I/O instructions: in a small system the highest address line could be used to distinguish between memory (a15=0) and I/O (a15=1), so we get 32Kb for real memory (ROM and RAM) and 32 Kb for I/O.

Note that it is even possible to use the I/O addresses to access RAM, but that is less useful because there are only 256 I/O addresses and the addressing modes available for these addresses are very limited.

Comment: Does the microprocessor literally has 64kB of memory that can be accessed by the user ? or it saves some of the memory (for peripheral to be connected).

Comment: All of the operations described are accessed via 8085 program instructions.  You can "ask" for any memory or I/O location you want.  The hardware design dictates whether you'll find anything there when you access it.

Comment: @Shivam the up does not 'have' any memory, it can *address* 2^16 bytes of rom/ram/io, plus 2^8 bytes of io. How you divide that 2^16 over ROM, RAM and IO is up to the hardware designer. The chip doesn't care.

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning that in the days of the 8085, memory was not inexpensve - quite the opposite and systems with 64K of memory were not that common.

Answer (score -1):

Memory mapped :memory mapped is 16 bit address provide for I/o devices &control signals are MEMR and MEMW. data transfer is any registered and I/O. memory related instruction  -ex :STA, CDA, MOV

Comment: Please re-write this answer more clearly. As it is written now, your answer is illegible.